# document.execCommand to execute superscript and subscript doesn't work in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a kind of text editor using :`document.execCommand('" + sFormatString + "',false,null);` where `sFormatString` is either 'superscript' or 'subscript' . It works in IE 8 but it doesn't work in both Chrome and Firefox. the execCommand will generate `<super>` or `<sub>` element  to make the text superscripted or subscribed. Any one knows how to make it work in FF and Chrome?or any other solution to this case?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. For me, the problem was due to some "normalization" CSS altering `vertical-align: baseline` for sup and sub tags. Overriding that CSS and setting sub to `vertical-align: sub` and sup to `vertical-align: super` fixed it.

Comment: Thanks,I ve found another solution which is attaching this css

sup {
 font-size:xx-small; 
 vertical-align:super;
}

sub {
 font-size:xx-small; 
 vertical-align:sub;
}

b{
 font-weight:bold;
}

i{
 font-style:italic;
}


li{
 
 margin-left:25px;
}